# How to determine next Delivery date based off today's date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have many stores with various delivery dates.  For instance, I have a store that gets a Monday Wednesday Friday delivery but I may input product for them on Saturday, so I need it to see today is Saturday and the next day it goes out is Monday. Or I have a store that I get product in on Tuesday and the next Delivery is Friday. I have many Stores with different delivery dates.  How do I determine the next delivery date in Excel?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you explain your problem in more detail and clarify exactly what you're having trouble with?  For anyone not familiar with your application, it is hard to understand your description.

Comment: Is the problem something like finding the number of days to next delivery by store?  Producing a calendar that shows scheduled activity?  Inputting a store to lookup the next delivery date?  The description talks about incoming deliveries, outgoing deliveries, preparing product for later delivery.  How do those things relate to the objective?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample set-up. I assumed Monday is day 1 of the week.

Formula in Cell...

D3 - =WEEKDAY(C3,2)

E3 - =WEEKDAY(C3,2)

F3 - =VLOOKUP(E3,$K$3:$L$10,2,FALSE)-D3+C3 (I believe this is the delivery date you were looking for)

L4 - =VLOOKUP(K4,$I$4:$J$10,2,FALSE) - drag it down

[image]